# OUYA Development Environment

Tags: android, google-play, ouya

Based on the information available on [OUYA's Kickstarter page](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ouya/ouya-a-new-kind-of-video-game-console), they mention the system is built on Android, but the games aren't necessarily Android ports.

Does this mean we can develop a game once and publish to Google Play and OUYA with one package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has its own exclusive store. And the games wont be direct port from andriod there will be slight differences

Comment: I am sure porting to Google Play won't be difficult.

Comment: Android games will need to be very slightly modified to run on OUYA but the changes won't affect their ability to run on Android, so you can just take your Android game and make it OUYA capable and you only need a single apk for both.

Answer (score 1):

I took one of my Android games that had been happily sitting and being downloaded on the Google Play store for a year and built it on my Ouya ( when it first arrived ) and it ran with no issues and without any code changes ( its an OpenGL realtime game ).

All I had to do before I could release it on Ouya was to replace/comment out the touch screen controls and replace them with Ouya control methods ( which are all in the Ouya SDK that is free to download from their site ). I also had to build in Ouya's payment system ( again in the SDK and pretty easy ).

It was then accepted and published on Ouya without any problems.

If I had to do the opposite (i.e. I developed it via Eclipse with Android SDK on Ouya ) it would be just as easy. I would just have to develop a control interface that worked with touch screens ( which for a Joystick is somewhat more complex then just programming for the analogue controls of a Joystick ) and remove all the Ouya payment routines.

Please let me know if you want more detail.